# Access from VMWare (debian) to remote host (Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx, vmware-workstation, wsgi

I have created a web service using django, wsgi and nginx in ubuntu.(http://127.0.0.1:8000) . My network connection is NAT. I want to access to this web service from Linux in VMWare. How can I do this?

Comment: did you try using the external ip of the ubuntu? i.e. `http://external.ip.address:8000'? (you can get the address by running `ifconfig`

Comment: @Yaron yes "ping: unknown host http://external.ip.address:8000"

Comment: If you want to use `ping`, you should run it without the `:8000` part, try running it using web-browser...

Comment: I have access from vmware to ubuntu and from ubuntu to vmware. I want to give access to my localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000) . I haven't browser in vmware's linux

Comment: `localhost` is `local`, you are not suppose to use it outside of the machine (and yes, your VM is outside of the host `localhost` , why won't you use the external_ip of the host?

Comment: I changed nginx listen section. Now it is ok. Thanks Yaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NAT` but use `Bridge` in your VM Network Adapter. Also configure your web service and/or nginx to listen on the real IP of the VM and not only `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks. I could do this with NAT, but changing the nginx config.